# How to install Tor browser on elementary OS

Tags: release-freya, tor

I tried installing **Tor** from the software center and it does not open when I click it and hangs when I run it from the terminal.

I also tried download the 64-bit ZIP , extracting and running it but it says **Tor unexpectedly exited**.

Comment: using `sudo apt-get install tor` I can install it fine.  what's the error you're getting/where is it getting hung up?

Comment: It gets stuck at `May 22 06:54:38.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done.`

Comment: this is after running `sudo apt-get install tor`?

Comment: @TimothyGray Yes after installing it and running `tor` from the terminal

Comment: ok so the problem is more with running it rather than installing as such. will see what I can find out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) (I'm not sure if there's a version of this in the repositories).  Extract to a convenient location, and in a terminal window execute

`cd /path-to-extracted-folder/`

and then

`./start-tor-browser.desktop`

Tor should start now.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/316105/tor-browser-not-opening

Comment: I tried that as well but the only thing that happens, is that Loki opens an editor and displays the script, but it does not run. Regards, Dragomrak

Comment: you need to find the executable tor file in your extracted folder run it. For example ./tor.sh    The file Timothy Gray was telling you to run is the desktop shortcut, not the executable. But the executable file and path will be listed in that file.But if you look at the instructions he linked it says to run ./start-tor-browser, not ./start-tor-browser.desktop. So give that a try.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I'll give it a try. :-) Regards, Dragomrak

Answer (score 0):

The answer Timothy Gray provides works for me.
But I wanted to have the Tor-application integrated into my Graphical Desktop environment, and put it in the Dock for easy access.

When you open the file "start-tor-browser.desktop" into an editor, you can see one line that is important for this:

```
You can also add Tor Browser to your desktop's application menu
by running './start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app'
```

So I tried

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach --register-app'...
Tor Browser has been registered as a desktop app for this user in ~/.local/share/applications/
```

After that I could look up the Tor-browser in the Applications-menu (or with `<Windows-key><spacebar>`) and choose for 'Keep in dock'.