# How do I set Tor Browser as the default browser for elementaryOS?

Tags: release-hera

Unfortunately, Tor Browser's installation process is quite convoluted and seems to skip some of the traditional amenities of a browser, (including being recognized by System Settings as a browser). In order to install the browser, I downloaded the latest Linux version of Tor Browser from the Tor Project website, and ran the following commands:

```
$ tar xvf tor-browser-linux64-9.0.7_en-US.tar.xz
$ mv tor-browser_en-US/* ~/.local/share/applications/.
$ /usr/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
```

This worked to register Tor Browser with the elementaryOS application launcher. However, Tor Browser did not show up in the `System Settings > Applications > Default > Web Browser` dropdown; only the other browsers I had installed.

At first I tried `update-alternatives`. I tried setting `x-www-browser` and `gnome-www-browser` with the commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser ~/.local/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop 1000
```

and

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser gnome-www-browser ~/.local/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop 1000
```

*please note that this `.desktop` file is also the executable for the browser.*

Neither of these worked. Next, I tried using `gsettings`, but tab completion on `org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.` with the command `gsettings get` showed only the following options:

```
org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.office
org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.office.calendar
org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.office.tasks
```

which, given that it doesn't have the full list of application types elementaryOS supports in System Settings, I assume is an incomplete list unused by the main OS.

**How do I set Tor Browser as the default browser for elementaryOS?**

Comment: Have you tried this post? https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/21904

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out by doing the following:

```
~/.local/share/applications
./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
```

Now Tor is sitting in my Applications launch area. I had no idea hwo to do this until I saw your instructions above. Many thanks.